# Changing default email color in Mail.app does not take effect

Tags: macos, mail.app

I have parametered  my Mail (Mac) so that the font color of all my emails are Green, yet each time I write an email, I must change the color myself.   Why didn't it take?  Which box should I have/not check(ed)?

Answer (score 1):

Apple doesn't yet offer the feature you want.  There are various workarounds like reusing a draft where you have set the color you want, creating custom stationery, composing your message as part of a sig set to your desired color, etc.